# How to get mathematica to carry out a Sum when only part of it is defined?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sum

I'm having a sum like this:

```
Sum[1 + x[i], {i, 1, n}]
```

Mathematica doesn't simplify it any more. What would I need to do so it translates it into:

```
n + Sum[x[i],{i,1,n}]
```

Comment: I don't believe it will do this automatically.  Perhaps if you described why you need this, or post your *actual* problem, then we could help

Comment: I don't see what the problem with this function. `Sum[1,{i,1,N}]` evaluates I would expect it to `N`. In my case I want to calculate error propagation so the specific funtion would be: `Sum[sigma+(x[i]-X)^2,{i,1,N}]`.

Comment: Is the issue that you are using `N` as the end parameter, which has a special meaning in Mathematica? Try small n instead.

Comment: ok - fixed n to small. To be honest I'm very confused now as this transformations seems so easy on the paper and is so complicated in Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica, while capable of quite a lot, is just a giant calculator that happens to be able to do algebra. So, while some things are simple, others can be more complex, often maddeningly so. Try to separate a function into real and imaginary parts, sometime, especially if they have numerical coefficients, like `1 + I`. Also, don't be so hasty to simplify, sometimes the [simplification](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77326/2283) can cause you to miss something, and that is why Mathematica is very conservative in the simplifications it employs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
Distribute[Sum[1 + x[i], {i, 1, n}]]
```

which returns:

```
n + Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK `Sum` simply won't give partial answers.  But you can always split off the additive part manually, or semi-automatically.  Taking your example,

```
In[1]:= sigma + (x[i] - X)^2 // Expand

Out[1]= sigma + X^2 - 2 X x[i] + x[i]^2
```

There's nothing we can do with the parts that contain `x[i]` without knowing anything about `x[i]`, so we just split off the rest:

```
In[2]:= Plus @@ Cases[%, e_ /; FreeQ[e, x[i]]]

Out[2]= sigma + X^2

In[3]:= Sum[%, {i, 1, n}]

Out[3]= n (sigma + X^2)
```

---

Unrelated: It is a good idea never to use symbols starting with capital letters to avoid conflicts with builtins.  `N` has a meaning already, and you shouldn't use it as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

A quick and dirty way would be to use `Thread`, so for example

```
Thread[Sum[Expand[sigma + (x[i] - X)^2], {i, 1, n}], Plus, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be

```
Total[Sum[#, {i, 1, n}] & /@ {sigma, x[i]}]
```

[image]

If your expression is longer, this should give you the answer without having to manually split the terms

```
expr = sigma + (x[i] + i)^2 + Cos[Sin[i - x[i]]];
Total[Sum[#, {i, 1, n}] & /@ Level[expr, {1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in an easy to understand manner with rules:

```
sumofsumsrule = Sum[a_+b_,{i_,c_,d_}] :> Sum[a,{i,c,d}]+Sum[b,{i,c,d}];
expandsummandrule = Sum[a_,{i_,c_,d_}] :> Sum[Expand[a],{i,c,d}];
MyRules = {sumofsumsrule, expandsummandrule};
```

Now, if you are messing around, you can use this (here are some examples):

```
error = Sum[sigma+(x[i]-X)^2,{i,1,n}]

error /. sumofsumsrule

% /. expandsummandrule

error //. MyRules
```